# Ajax submit post data to a get url

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, get

Is it possible to mix post and get in ajax? Specifically have a form POST data to a url with get variables?

In html and PHP I would normally do this:

```
<form action="script.php?foo=bar" method="POST">
    ...insert inputs and buttons here... 
</form>
```

And the PHP script would handle it based on logic/classes.

I have tried the following and several variations to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formSubmitButton').click(function() {
            var data = $('#valueToBePassed').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    //contentType: 'application/json',
                    url: "script.php?foo=bar",
                    data: data,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function(returnData) {
                        $('#content').html( returnData );
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

Is this even possible? If so what am I doing wrong. I do not feel as if I am trying to reinvent the wheel as it is already possible and used regularly (whether or not if it is recommended) by plenty of scripts (granted they are php based).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out the below jsfiddle URL and

https://jsfiddle.net/cnhd4cjn/

```
  url: "script.php?data="+data, //to get it in the URL as query param
  data:"data="+data, // to get it in the payload data
```

Also check the network tab in dev tools to inspect the URL pattern on click of the submit button

Comment: Ultimately it was a variation of all the answers but the fiddle you did gave me the insight I needed as to how to fix my mistake. What I was missing is that the ajax call happened after the initial ajax call (the one that loads the form) and I needed to wrap it in a function and do an onSubmit.

Answer (score 1):

You can, here's what I do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#formSubmitButton').click(function() {
        // My GET variable that I will be passing to my URL
        getVariable = $('#valueToBePassed').val();
        // Making an example object to use in my POST and putting it into a JSON string
        var obj = {
            'testKey': 'someTestData'
        }
        postData = JSON.stringify(obj);
        // Jquery's AJAX shorthand POST function, I'm just concatenating the GET variable to the URL
        $.post('myurl.com?action=' + getVariable, postData, function(data) {
            JSONparsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
            nonparsedData = data;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: When I used this (and I think a slightly modified version of this will work, multiple get variables) it called the script, but it put the value as a get in the browser so now the url is script.php?valueId=value.

Answer (score 1):

I can see 1 syntax error in you code .

use

```
 data: {data:data},
```

instead of

```
 data: data,
```

and then try to access like

```
$_POST['data']; and $_GET['foo'];
```

But i have never tried the `GET` params inside a `POST` request :) , this is only a suggestion.